# Dynamic Radar Chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, data-visualization

I've created a dynamic radar chart which allows manipulation of points by clicking. My code works, but I'm sure the large amount of `if`.. `else if` statements can be processed in a loop, because it is clearly a repetition.

I thought about how I could use a loop to do it, but couldn't figure it out because of the way the coordinates of points are located.

My main concern is the `if`.. `else if` because it looks scary.

Here is live [demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmotawaze/rn4y7n15/);

and here is the whole javascript:

```
var canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canv1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var point_xy = document.getElementById('point_xy');
var temp = [];
var point_xy_cords = [
  []
];
var pentagon_one = 24;
var pentagon_two = 18;
var pentagon_three = 12;
var pentagon_four = 6;
var pentagon_five = 0;
var circles = [];
var contx = canv.getContext('2d');
var contx1 = canv1.getContext('2d');
var j = 0;
var offsetX = canv1.offsetLeft;
var offsetY = canv1.offsetTop;
contx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

function drawShape(ctx, x, y, points, radius1, radius2, alpha0) {
  //points: number of points (or number of sides for polygons)
  //radius1: "outer" radius of the star
  //radius2: "inner" radius of the star (if equal to radius1, a polygon is drawn)
  //angle0: initial angle (clockwise), by default, stars and polygons are 'pointing' up
  var i, angle, radius;
  if (radius2 !== radius1) {
    points = 2 * points;
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= points; i++) {
    angle = i * 2 * Math.PI / points - Math.PI / 2 + alpha0;
    radius = i % 2 === 0 ? radius1 : radius2;
    temp = [(x + radius * Math.cos(angle)), (y + radius * Math.sin(angle))];
    ctx.lineTo(temp[0, 0], temp[0, 1]);
    point_xy_cords[j++] = temp;

  }
  point_xy.textContent = point_xy_cords;
}

function style(ctx, fill) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#bada55";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  if (fill) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(35, 63, 57, 0.8)";
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke()
  }

  //contx.fill();
}

var radius = 5;

function points(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'gold';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  ctx.stroke();
}

var Circle = function(x, y, radius) {
  this.left = x - radius;
  this.top = y - radius;
  this.right = x + radius;
  this.bottom = y + radius;
};

var radius_size = 100;

function drawBackgroundPentagons(ctx) {
  for (var x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    drawShape(ctx, 120, 120, 5, radius_size, radius_size, 0);
    style(ctx);
    ctx.closePath();
    radius_size = radius_size - 20;
  }

}

function drawMainPentagon(ctx, points) {

  contx1.beginPath();
  contx1.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
  for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[x][0], points[x][1]);
  }
  style(ctx, "fill");
  ctx.closePath();
}
drawBackgroundPentagons(contx);

//draw main Pentagon
//0, 6, 12, 18, 24
test = [];
var start = 24;
for (var x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
  test[x] = point_xy_cords[start];
  start++;
}
drawMainPentagon(contx1, test);

//Draw all points
var n = 30;
while (n > 0) {
  var circle = new Circle(point_xy_cords[n][0], point_xy_cords[n][1], 8);
  circles.push(circle);
  points(contx1, point_xy_cords[n][0], point_xy_cords[n][1]);
  n--;
}

function handleMouseDown(e, message) {
  mouseX = parseInt(e.pageX - offsetX);
  mouseY = parseInt(e.pageX - offsetY);
  point_xy.textContent = (message);
}

canv1.onmousedown = function(e) {
  //var clickedX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  //var clickedY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  var x = parseInt(e.pageX - 20);
  var y = parseInt(e.pageY - 20);
  var pointX = test[1][0];
  var pointY = test[1][1];
  var dx = x - (pointX);
  var dy = y - (pointY);
  var distsq = dx * dx + dy * dy;
  var rsq = 25;
  var array = [4, 3, 5, 3, 0];

  //handleMouseDown(e, x + " x | " + pointX + " pointx |" + pointY + " pointy | " + y + " y | " + dx + " dx | " + dy + " dy|" + distsq + " distsq | " + offsetX);


  //contx1.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  //drawMainPentagon(contx1, test);
  //
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    if (x < circles[i].right && x > circles[i].left && y > circles[i].top && y < circles[i].bottom) {
      //alert ('clicked number ' + (i + 1));
      handleMouseDown(e, "point clicked: " + i + " | test object: " + test);
      if (i == 6) {
        test[0] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_one];
        test[5] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_one];
      } else if (i == 12) {
        test[0] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_two];
        test[5] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_two];
      } else if (i == 18) {
        test[0] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_three];
        test[5] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_three];
      } else if (i == 24) {
        test[0] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_four];
        test[5] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_four];
      } else if (i == 25) {
        test[0] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_five];
        test[5] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_five];
      }

      else if (i == 5) {
        test[1] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_one + 1];
      }
            else if (i == 11) {
        test[1] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_two + 1];
      }
      else if (i == 17) {
        test[1] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_three + 1];
      }
      else if (i == 23) {
        test[1] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_four + 1];
      }
      else if (i == 29) {
        test[1] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_five + 1];
      }

      else if (i == 4) {
        test[2] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_one + 2];
      }
            else if (i == 10) {
        test[2] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_two + 2];
      }
      else if (i == 16) {
        test[2] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_three + 2];
      }
      else if (i == 22) {
        test[2] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_four + 2];
      }
      else if (i == 28) {
        test[2] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_five + 2];
      }

      else if (i == 3) {
        test[3] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_one + 3];
      }
            else if (i == 9) {
        test[3] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_two + 3];
      }
      else if (i == 15) {
        test[3] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_three + 3];
      }
      else if (i == 21) {
        test[3] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_four + 3];
      }
      else if (i == 27) {
        test[3] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_five + 3];
      }

      else if (i == 2) {
        test[4] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_one + 4];
      }
            else if (i == 8) {
        test[4] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_two + 4];
      }
      else if (i == 14) {
        test[4] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_three + 4];
      }
      else if (i == 20) {
        test[4] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_four + 4];
      }
      else if (i == 26) {
        test[4] = point_xy_cords[pentagon_five + 4];
      }
    }
  }
  contx1.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  var n = 30;
    while (n > 0) {
    points(contx1, point_xy_cords[n][0], point_xy_cords[n][1]);
    n--;
    }
  drawMainPentagon(contx1, test);
};
```

I am looking for some direction as to how I can avoid the massive repetition that is taking place, and increase the efficiency of the overall code.

Comment: Note that you can make live demos directly in Stack Exchange by pressing Ctrl-M in the question editor.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher Would my edit qualify as a new question in Stackoverflow, or codereview?

Comment: If your new code is having issues then [SO]  would be the place to ask a new question. For questions on Code Review you should consider to wait some more days because answers here may take some more time. Asking a new question is ok but you should include a link to this question and show in the question that it is a follow up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking mostly about the huge statement in the `onmouseclick` handler? I would start by making your `Circle` class a bit smarter, give it the information it needs and move some of the logic there. More specifically I would let each point know which pentagon axis it is on and it's index from the center. Then add methods to `Circle` like `containsPoint(x,y)`, `draw(context)` and most importantly `clicked()`. Your code would then look something like:

```
function onmouseclicked() {
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    var circle = circles[i];
    if (circle.containsPoint(clickedX, clickedY) {
      circle.clicked();
      return;
    }
  }
}

Circle.prototype.clicked = function() {
  test[axis] = {x: this.x, y: this.y };
}
```

I would start here, see how ti affects your code and then come back for a second review if you want.

Note: A lot of your intermediate variables like `point_xy_coords`, `pentagon_one` are unnecessary. If you do keep `point_xy_cords` make it more structure. Currently you are doing something like `point_xy_coords[axis*5+index]`, instead do an array of arrays `point_xy_coords[axis][index]`. Also I wouldn't make your `temp` array have 6 points. Just draw the extra line in your `drawMainPentagon` routine.

Comment: ahh, it makes sense. I will follow your guide and get back to you when I'm done. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again, I managed to edit my code with your help, could you please review it one more time.

Comment: Are your changes somewhere I can see them?

Comment: I  just posted a question at StackOverflow because I'm having issues figuring out which corner to change after implementing your code review. When I fix that issue, I will post it here again for another review. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965497/dynamic-radar-chart-keeping-track-of-points